# Dividing array among fixed number of threads

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading, split

I want to split an array **Data[ ]** of variable size among **fixed number of threads** in a fair way

**Case 1: Divide Data[7] among 4 threads fairly**

> ```
> Thread ID 0: Data[0], Data[1]
> Thread ID 1: Data[2], Data[3]
> Thread ID 2: Data[4], Data[5]
> Thread ID 3: Data[6]
> ```

Presently my code divides the array unfairly

**Case 2: Divide Data[7] among 4 threads**

> ```
> Thread ID 0: Data[0]
> Thread ID 1: Data[1]
> Thread ID 2: Data[2]
> Thread ID 3: Data[3], Data[4], Data[5], Data[6]
> ```

Here is a the code which implements **Case 2**.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const unsigned int NUMELEM = 7;
const unsigned int THREADCNT = 4;

unsigned int elemPerThread = NUMELEM/THREADCNT;
unsigned int remElements = NUMELEM % THREADCNT;

int Data[NUMELEM];

void DoStuff( unsigned int const& thid )
{
    unsigned int startIndex = thid*elemPerThread;
    unsigned int endIndex = startIndex + elemPerThread;

    cout<<"Thread ID "<<thid<<": ";
    for( unsigned int index = startIndex; index != endIndex; index++ )
    {
        cout<<"Data["<<index<<"], ";
    }

    if( (thid+1) == THREADCNT )
    {
        for( unsigned i = 0; i!= remElements; i++)
        {
            cout<<"Data["<<endIndex + i<<"], ";
        }
    }

    cout<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    for( unsigned int thid = 0; thid != THREADCNT; thid++)
    {
        // TBU: Make multithreaded
        DoStuff( thid );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I want solution to **Case 1**

Comment: Hint: the reminder defines how many threads should receive one element more than the rest. Compare the thread number with the reminder, and calculate start and end indices differently depending on the comparison.

Comment: You will want to make this an array of 70,000 rather than 7, and place jobs of 5,000 indices each on a queue. Processing 7 items is hardly worth spawning threads (unless they are massively complicated compute tasks). Using a queue, you can be sure that if threads do not run at the same speed (which is likely the case), the fastest thread which will be done early will pick up work rather than going idle. You always want to keep all available resources (i.e. processors) as much busy as possible.

Comment: The number of jobs on a thread can be easily calculated by (NUMELEM/THREADCNT)+(thid < NUMELEM % THREADCNT ? 1 : 0). The thing to do is use this to precalculate the start and end indexes for DoStuff and pass them as an argument to dostuff: `for (unsigned int thid = 0,start_indx = 0; thid < THREADCNT; thid++) { unsigned int endindx = start_indx+(NUMELEM/THREADCNT)+(thid < NUMELEM % THREADCNT ? 1 : 0); DoStuff(thid,start_indx,endindx); start_indx=endindx;}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for my quick and dirty code, but I think it does its job.

```
void DoStuff( unsigned int const& thid )
{
    cout<<"ThID:"<<thid<<endl;
    const unsigned numTasks = NUMELEM/THREADCNT, numTougherThreads = NUMELEM%THREADCNT;
    for( unsigned int index0 = (thid < numTougherThreads ? thid * (numTasks+1) : NUMELEM - (THREADCNT - thid) * numTasks), index = index0; index < index0 + numTasks + (thid < numTougherThreads) ; ++index)
    {
        cout<<"Data["<<index<<"], ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

http://ideone.com/3CeMm8 (a fork from @dasblinkenlight's)

The idea behind my code is:

1. `thread0` is responsible for the first `(NUMELEM/THREADCNT)+1` tasks; `thread1` is for the next `(NUMELEM/THREADCNT)+1` tasks...
2. Meanwhile the **last** thread is responsible for the **last** `(NUMELEM/THREADCNT)` tasks; the **second last** thread is for the **second last** `(NUMELEM/THREADCNT)` tasks...
3. Only the first `(NUMELEM%THREADCNT)` threads ("tougher" threads) have `(NUMELEM/THREADCNT)+1` tasks.